# I installed cygwin on Windows 8 recently. When I try to run an executable file using './' , it gives me the following error. How do I fix this?

Tags: shell, unix, cygwin

I installed cygwin on Windows 8 recently. When I try to run an executable file using './' , it gives me the following error. How do I fix this?
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: not a programming question. Move to superuser

Answer (score 0):

In the cygwin if we need to see output 
 **sh filename.sh**
Example: sh hello.sh
working good getting output in cigwin

In the unix terminal  if we need to see output 
 **./filename.sh**
Example:  ./hello.sh
working good getting output in cigwin aswell as linux